# File not showing in Jenkins root directory

Tags: git, jenkins, devops

I am new to Jenkins and I made a simple Freestyle Project where I used my git repository using (Source Code Management --> Git). However when I tried working on this directory I couldn't. The "dir" command showed this

```
> dir C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\workspace\dotnetJob

09/08/2020  04:17 PM    <DIR>          .
09/08/2020  04:17 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  178,034,421,760 bytes free
```

However when I go to this location I can see the files have been pulled successfully. I have tried changing "JENKINS_HOME" but that didn't work.

I am not sure whether I was facing a timeout issue so I tried increasing the timeout for clone and also tried "Wipe out repository and force clone" but that didn't work either. Please help.

EDIT : No changes to default config of freestyle job except what i share below

[image: Source Code Manag]

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the configuration image of you freestyle project. That will be helpful for us to understand the issue.

Comment: I just installed Jenkins didn't use docker for this

Comment: @eerieH Maybe UnknownBeast was referring to a screenshot ("image") of your freestyle project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to work in the job folder created by Jenkins to checkout its repository.
Plus, the configuration could have a "cleanup workspace" after build option activated.

It is better to clone the repository (independently of Jenkins) and work in that local clone.